# Parsing HTML/XML with XPath in node.js

Tags: html, xml, node.js, xpath

I'm trying to write an XPath statement to fetch the contents of each row in a table, but only when the 2nd column of each row is not set to "TBA". 
The page I am working off [this page](http://au.cybergamer.com/pc/csgo/ladder/scheduled/). I am new to using XPath.

I've come up with the following statement, which I've managed to test successfully (or appears successful anyway) with an online XPath tester, but have been unable to figure out how to apply it in node.js:

`//*[@id="body_column_left"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/[not(contains(./td[2], 'TBA'))]`

This is my attempt below, I've tried variations but I can't get it to even validate as a valid XPath statement and as a result I've been lost in not very helpful stack traces:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var xpath = require('xpath');
var parse5 = require('parse5');
var xmlser = require('xmlserializer');
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var request = require('request');

var getHTML = function (url, callback) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback(body) // return the HTML
        }
    })
}

getHTML("http://au.cybergamer.com/pc/csgo/ladder/scheduled/", function (html) {
    var parser = new parse5.Parser();
    var document = parser.parse(html.toString());
    var xhtml = xmlser.serializeToString(document);
    var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xhtml);
    var select = xpath.useNamespaces({"x": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});    
    var nodes = select("//x:*[@id=\"body_column_left\"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/[not(contains(./td[2], 'TBA'))]", doc);
    console.log(nodes);    
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) , would be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response @hassansin, I will take a look into using `cheerio`.

Comment: I ended up solving this with Cheerio, thanks @hassansin :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue using `cheerio`instead of `xpath`:

See below:

```
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.s_grad br').replaceWith("\n");
    $('.s_grad thead').remove();
    $('.s_grad tr').each(function(i, elem) {
        rows[i] = $(this).text();
        rows[i] = rows[i].replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, ""); // remove empty newlines
        matches.push(new match($(this).find('a').attr('href').substring(7).slice(0, -1))) // create matches
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using this [`xpath-html`](https://github.com/hieuvp/xpath-html), I loved its simplicity.

```js
const xpath = require("xpath-html");

const nodes = xpath
  .fromPageSource(html)
  .findElements("//img[starts-with(@src, 'https://cloud.shopback.com')]");
```

Comment: While using this library Im getting this error TypeError: this.html.charCodeAt is not a function. Whats the cause of this.

Comment: Hi @AmnaArshad, can you create an issue on its GitHub repo?